# Zone Alarm only works with “disable driver signing”

Tags: windows-7

the only way I can get my Zone Alarm to work is to start up on f8 and disable driver signing. I have tried bcdedit with no luck. I have used the same win7 pro disc in my other two computers and no problem. is it a problem with my Toshiba laptop?